# How to do using Angular A countdown timer after 00:00:00 will come -00:00:01, not 23:59:59

Tags: angular

When I use Angular's date pipe after it goes down to 00:00:00 it starts 23:59:59
This is my code

```
{{(balance_orginal_e_prints-use) * 1000 | date:'HH:mm:ss':'UTC'}}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You're formatting the value as **date**, so this is expected. There's no notion of a negative date value, so Angular tries to catch this unexpected value and do something sensible with it.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, so what's the solution?

Comment: create your custom pipe

Answer (score 1):

I did build a suitable pipe

```
  transform(s: number): string {
let sec_num = s
s = Math.abs(s)
var hours:any   = Math.floor(s / 3600);
var minutes:any = Math.floor((s - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
var seconds:any = s - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

if (hours   < 10) {hours   = "0"+hours;}
if (minutes < 10) {minutes = "0"+minutes;}
if (seconds < 10) {seconds = "0"+seconds;}
return (sec_num < 0 ? "-" : "")+hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
```

}